# Pass Texture to Uniform with CVOpenGLESTextureCache in OpenGL ES

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm trying to apply a video file as a texture in OpenGL ES on iOS 5.0+ using CVOpenGLESTextureCache.

I've found Apple's [RosyWriter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011110) sample code, and have been reading through it.

The question I have is:

How are the textures finally being delivered to the uniforms in the fragment shader?

In the RosyWriterPreviewView class, I follow it all the way up to

```
glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(texture), 
               CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(texture))
```

after which some texture parameters are specified.

However, I don't see the texture uniform (sampler2D videoframe) ever being explicitly referenced by the sample code. The texture-sending code I've become used to would look something like:

```
GLint uniform = glGetUniformLocation(program, "u_uniformName");
```

with a subsequent call to actually send the texture to the uniform:

```
glUniform1i(GLint location, GLint x);
```

So I know that SOMEhow RosyWriter is delivering the texture to the uniform in its fragment shader, but I can't see how and where it's happening.

In fact, the sample code includes the comment where it builds up the OpenGL program:

```
// we don't need to get uniform locations in this example
```

Any help on why this is & how the texture is getting sent over would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the RosyWriter example, I think the reason they're able to get away without using `glUniformi()` at any point for the `videoframe` uniform is that they're binding the input texture to texture unit 0.

When specifying a uniform value for a texture, the value you use is the texture unit that texture is bound to. If you don't set a value for a uniform, I believe it should default to 0, so by binding the texture to unit 0 always they never have to set a value for the `videoframe` uniform. It will still pull in the texture attached to unit 0.